# Tab bar; childView segues

Tags: swift

I'm trying to make an app which has a Tab bar View with 2 Views. The first contains a tableView. With the second you can add Elements to the tableView. Now I want to be able to communicate between the to Views

Are there segues when you switch tabs in the tab bar controller? How can I intercept them? If not, are there any other possibilities to communicate between the two Views?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can intercept the actual switch between view controllers by using [UITabBarControllerDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITabBarControllerDelegate_Protocol/) with the method  [tabBarController:didSelectViewController:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITabBarControllerDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITabBarControllerDelegate/tabBarController:didSelectViewController:):

> Tells the delegate that the user selected an item in the tab bar.

There is a neat implementation you can do by going to the object library and search for "object":

[image]

Drag it to your Tab bar view controller and set it's delegate by ctrl + drag.

Choose it:

[image]

and set a custom class in the inspector:

[image]

When you right click the Object you should see:

[image]

Here is an example of your CustomClass:

```
class CustomClass : NSObject, UITabBarControllerDelegate
{
   func tabBarController(tabBarController: UITabBarController, didSelectViewController viewController: UIViewController)
   {
   }
}
```

While the viewController param is:

> The view controller that the user selected. In iOS v3.0 and later, this could be the same view controller that was already selected.

Which means you need to check which VC is it.

Comment: I've done it, but the tabBarController() don't get executed.

Comment: This is exactly what you need, take in mind that your VC need to be tab bar view controller.
If the callback isn't working it means that you didn't set the delegate as you should. Thus, the callbacks happens but NOT to your customClass.

I have updated the answer with how your Object should look like when you right click on it.

Comment: thanks, I've found a solution myself. `let ctrl = super.parentViewController as! UITabBarController
        
        for saveCtrl in ctrl.viewControllers! {
            if saveCtrl is SaveViewController {
                print("Worked")
                let newSaveCtrl = saveCtrl as! SaveViewController
                newSaveCtrl.saveDelegate =
                    {(newValue: String) in
                        
                        self.Elemente.append(newValue)
                        
                    }
            }
        }`

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a solution myself:

```
let ctrl = super.parentViewController as! UITabBarController

    for saveCtrl in ctrl.viewControllers! {
        if saveCtrl is SaveViewController {
            print("Worked")
            let newSaveCtrl = saveCtrl as! SaveViewController
            newSaveCtrl.saveDelegate =
                {(newValue: String) in

                    self.Elemente.append(newValue)

                }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Who exactly calls it ? Is there a delegate for that ? How do you intercept the actual tap by the user ?

Comment: this happens in the viewDidLoad() of the VC with the tableView. When you start the App, this VC shows up and this code gets executed. In my SaveController, which is the one which adds Elements to the tableView, the saveDelegate gets initialized with that code and if I hit save, it runs the saveDelegate. Hope you understand it :P